# how to make apscheduler forever in linux

Tags: python, linux, apscheduler

- I want to run apscheduler forever in Linux
- But. The apscheduler not work when I close the terminal.

here is my code

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime

def tick():
    text = 'Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now()
    saveLog(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'cron', hour=9)
    scheduler.start()
```

> Run Python In Terminal

```
python3 my.py &
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) in Linux will allow you to run instances of your application in the background,

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [nohup](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html)

```
nohup my.py &
```